# PHP preg_split anyway to keep the dividing string ??

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, explode, preg-split

If i have the following string

```
$string = "
0001

a
b
c
d
e

0002

f
g
h
i
j
";
```

I am splitting it with `$r = preg_split("/\d{4}\n/", $string);` and that works fine but i also want to include the dividing string..

i.e. at the moment this gives me

```
Array [0] {

a
b
c
d
e
}

 => [1] {

f
g
h
i
j
}
```

but i want it to include the divider i.e.

```
Array [0] {
0001

a
b
c
d
e
}

 => [1] {
0002

f
g
h
i
j
}
```

Hope that makes sense..

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [*lookahead* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_split("/(?=\d{4})/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Kyz38Pbu)

Don't know why you have `<br/>` in your expression. There is no HTML in your string (at least not in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match_all instead.

```
preg_match_all("/\d{4}[^\d]+/", $string, $matches);
```

The matches will contain all the parts of your string that start with 4 digits and end right before the next digit.

You also may filter out the `<br>` using brackets.